# HTML5 time input step attribute not working in Android

Tags: android, html, cordova

Using the following code

```
<input type="time" step="1800">
```

Step=1800 seconds restricts the time input to 30 minute steps. This works as expected in a desktop browser. But it appears to have no effect on android (4.4.4).

Anyone know of a solution or workaround to make this (restrict time input to 30 minute intervals) work natively in Android ? As a last resort, I can try the cordova datepicker plugin (not sure if it allows for steps), but a native html5 solution would be preferred by far.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's not supported in most mobile platforms, see http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html

Scroll to the bottom to see "step" property.

As an alternative, unfortunately I can't think anything on top of my head, but I would probably go with implementing it on my own with divs and js.

Comment: yeah, looks like a custom datepicker is the only alternative for stepped time input at this point, which is a pity as we lose the native platform feel.

Comment: Does the answer still hold true today?