# HTML5 “time” input interval dose not work on mobile browser

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-build, html-framework-7

I make mobile application with PhoneGap
I uses html5 and jquery

I have page contain this input :

step attribute, to increment minutes , it does not work on mobile's browser  or mobile application
but it is working in browsers desktop 
I need help to fix it, please

Comment: What are you browsing with on mobile? The step attribute is new to HTML5 and some older browsers won't recognize it.

Comment: Here is a link I found with a similar question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033115/html5-time-input-step-attribute-not-working-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: is any javascript or jquery fix this ?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do exactly, but JQuery / Javascript is going to be the way to go if you need some sort of timer or clock.

Comment: If you give me a clear goal and a block of code, I might be able to find you some JQuery examples that would work.

Comment: I used framework7 with PhoneGap  I have not any code just I need time picker suitable for android and IOS  , Can you make it control the MINUTES part of this control, so if it is 15 then the options are :-
9.00
9.15
9.30
9.45
 If it is 10 then the options are 
9.00
9.10
9.20
9.30
9.40
9.50

Comment: An Alex James Brown has a good JSFiddle of a date picker. He has posted his code online and you can take code from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/v6hdS/) to get what you want.

Comment: are you know any Cordova plugin for time picker with feature to control the interval minutes increment  instead of jquery mobile